# Temperature Lag calculation

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, cross-correlation, lags

I am working on a data science project on an industrial machine.  This machine has two heating infrastructures.  (fuel and electricity).  It uses these two heatings at the same time, and I am trying to estimate the temperature value that occurs in the thermocouple as a result of this heating. However, this heating process takes place with some delay/lag. In other words, the one-unit change I have made in fuel and electrical heating is reflected in the thermocouple hours later. I want to find these hours, i.e. I'm trying to calculate the temperature change delay time on the thermocouple for the change in fuel and electricity.  These three data are non-stationary time series data.  I have data in frequency per second.  I thought of using cross correlation but having two different heat sources confuses me.  Which method do you think is better to use?  Also, should I keep them in units like kwh/m3 or convert them to heat calorie units?